# how to fix md5sum:"No such file or directory" error?

Tags: bash, unix, md5sum

I have a bash script which has to perform a `md5sum` on two files. The two files do exists in the path specified in the first argument of `md5sum`, however, I get a `no such file or directory` error for both of them.

The script is the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

md51=$(md5sum /tmp/data/hello | cut -d " " -f 1)
md52=$(md5sum /tmp/data/there | cut -d " " -f 1)

exit 0
```

and I cannot modify the script, since it has been given to me written like that. 
Do you have any idea why I get the `no such file or directory` error, even though the files do exist in the correct location? Might it be an issue related to my OS (which is Ubuntu 15.10 Wily) ?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure they exist in the context of how the script is being executed?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams  I think so: the script is in Desktop and the files are in Desktop/tmp/data/

Comment: Do you understand what the initial slash means?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams yes! And I know that without the initial / everything works fine, but I have been given the path with the initial "/" therefore where should I put the files in order for it to work?

Comment: ... In `/tmp/data`.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams yes I got it! I have been tricked because I had been using that tmp folder for other parts of my code but I had forgotten that I had removed the initial / to do so! So I guess I'll have to change it all up, thanks for putting me on the right path!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/home/yourname/Desktop/tmp/data/`
is a different location than `/tmp/data/`

`/` at the beginning of a path is the root directory. Kind of the unix counter-part to "C:\" of windows
( - very over-simplified explanation).

Comment: This was my first lesson to learn, navigating the file system.  find, top, free, locate, updatedb are all new things I, as a newb, did not know.